# Why did the bible called Jesus the first begotten of the dead when truly he was the first to come back from the dead?

Tags: revelation, 1-corinthians

Why was Jesus called the first begotten of the dead?

> But now is Christ risen from the dead, and become the firstfruits of them that slept.
> — 1 Corithians 15:20

> And from Jesus Christ, who is the faithful witness, and the first begotten of the dead, and the prince of the kings of the earth. Unto him that loved us, and washed us from our sins in his own blood
> — Revelation 1:5

Comment: πρωτοτοκος εκ των νεκρων _first-delivered out of the dead_. This means the first delivered ('delivery' like childbirth) _out of the state of_ death. This is Revelation 1:5 which I suggest should be the focus of the question, not the text above.

Comment: I am mystified why you choose 1 Cor 15:20 as it does not use the term "first-born".  First fruits and firstborn are quite different in meaning.

Comment: @Dottard, that reference was added as someone else's edit, andl ater my edit expanded it.